# ASIHTTPRequest, EXC_BAD_ACCESS when request did finished

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, selector, asihttprequest

I'm trying to do an asynchronous request with ASIHTTPRequest, but have some problem getting notified when the request is done.

```
-(void)doDownload{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.com/?"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:@"someValue" forKey:@"someField"];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished)];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

}
```

requestFinished is never called. I get an exception in ASIHTTPRequest.m, -handleStreamCompleted:

```
if (fileError) {
    [self failWithError:fileError];
} else {
    [self requestFinished];   <----- this call fails
}
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure that your class that implements `- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request` is still there when the request finishes? It looks to me like the class gets deallocated too early. Note that the `delegate` property does not retain its content.

You could add a `[self retain]` to `doDownload` and a `[self release]` to `- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request`, but make sure (!) that `[self release]` doesn't get called too often. This is also a possible memory leak if a request would never finish. It would be best to retain your class somewhere else.

You might also try to debug with `NSZombieEnabled` set to `YES` to find the error.

Comment: This seems to be the right answer. I have a lifetime management problem that needs solving. Now, I create a download-class, call a method, and immediately release. I must implement some callback system to let the download-instance owner to know when things are done. I would need this eventually any way, to hide progress views and update data etc. Thanks.

Comment: How can this be done when running with ARC? Please see my [topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355974).

Comment: Tosh. @tomute is right, the selector's name is requestFinished:, not requestFinished, that's the whole problem. No need to break your pretty little head over lifetime cycles and retains and stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Following line of your code seems to be wrong.

```
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished)];
```

**requestFinished** method has an argument (ASIHTTPRequest *).
Therefore you should add **":"**, when you set a selector like as follows.

```
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
```

Comment: I will take your word for it ;-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[request responseString];

Check retainCount of request before this call. Propably it equals zero :) If that - you shouldn't forget to retain it when you creates it in *doDownload* method.

Comment: I can't check requests retainCount in requestFinished, since requestFinished never get called.