# ASIHTTPRequestTester: Asynchronous not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest

I'm trying to make a App for iOS using ASIHTTPRequest, but I'm facing some issues using it. To demonstrate my problems, I've uploaded an test-project, which you can download from here: http://uploads.demaweb.dk/ASIHTTPRequestTester.zip.

I've created a WebService class which use the `ASIHTTPRequestDelegate` protocol:

```
#import "WebService.h"
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"

@implementation WebService

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"requestFinished");
}
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"requestFailed");
}

- (void) testSynchronous {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSLog(@"starting Synchronous");
    [request startSynchronous];
    NSError *error = [request error];
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"got response");
    }
}

- (void) testAsynchronous {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];

    NSLog(@"starting Asynchronous");
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

@end
```

The synchronous method is working fine, but the asynchronous is not working at all. First the requestFinished and requestFailed was never called and right now I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The two test-methods is called from my ViewController's `viewDidLoad`. I hope someone can help me making this work.

**EDIT1:**
As per [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164948), it is possible because of the `Automatic Reference Counting` which is enabled for my project. The topic advice to add a `[self retain]`, but I cannot do this with ARC  turned on. Anyone with a solution for this?

**EDIT2:**
Update as per answer from [MrMage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8369939/617413).

```
@interface ViewController()
@property (nonatomic,strong) WebService *ws;
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize ws = _ws;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setWs:[[WebService alloc] init]];
    [self.ws testSynchronous];
    [self.ws testAsynchronous];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add your `WebService` instance as a strong reference to an object that stays around for long enough (say your view controller), then tell that class to get rid of the `WebService` after it has done its job (i.e. in `requestFinished` and `requestFailed` you call back to the view controller, telling it to release the `WebService` instance).

Comment: Thank for your answer. Please see my `edit2` where I've added a strong property to the ViewController. It is working fine, but is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue on delegation with ASIHTTPRequest and ARC.

I just end up using blocks to solve it.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];

//set request like this to avoid retain cycle on blocks
__weak ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

//if request succeeded
[request setCompletionBlock:^{        
    [self requestFinished:request];
}];

//if request failed
[request setFailedBlock:^{        
    [self requestFailed:request];
}];

[request startAsynchronous];
```